# Displaying the BLOB file on frontend using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have a table named `listing_fees`

and I want to get the data by the `id` of `12`

the data that I want to get is a `BLOB` that is named `[BLOB - 205B]`

inside the `BLOB` file is an array like this:

`a:7:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:5:"label";s:8:"For Sale";s:6:"amount";s:4:"0.00";s:4:"days";s:1:"7";s:6:"images";s:1:"0";s:10:"categories";a:2:{s:3:"all";i:0;s:10:"categories";a:1:{i:0;i:30;}}s:10:"extra_data";N;}`

I don't understand a thing on this code.

I want to display it on the frontend of my html using PHP

what will I to display it?

SQL Query or something else.

Comment: Looks like a serialized php object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That data is in [PHP Serialized format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) you can decode it using [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Example

```
$data = 'a:7:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:5:"label";s:8:"For Sale";s:6:"amount";s:4:"0.00";s:4:"days";s:1:"7";s:6:"images";s:1:"0";s:10:"categories";a:2:{s:3:"all";i:0;s:10:"categories";a:1:{i:0;i:30;}}s:10:"extra_data";N;}';
$data = unserialize($data);

echo "<pre>" ;
foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
    if ($key == 'categories') {
        echo $key, " = ", $value['categories']['0'], PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $key, " = ", $value , PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
id = 1
label = For Sale
amount = 0.00
days = 7
images = 0
categories = 30
extra_data =
```

Answer (score 1):

The data in the `BLOB` column appears to be serialized data, not a file. Because of this, you don't want to just "output" it to the page - you'll want to unserialize it (via PHP's [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) method) and then process to be displayed, well, however it should be displayed. Taking the *exact* data you display in your question and passing using `unserialize()` on it gives me an array with the following:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [label] => For Sale
    [amount] => 0.00
    [days] => 7
    [images] => 0
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [all] => 0
            [categories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 30
                )

        )

    [extra_data] =>
)
```

A simple setup, to query the database and retrieve the column, would be:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT column_name FROM listing_fees WHERE id = 12');
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
$result->close();
```

To use the data that is in the `$data` array, you can do:

```
$blob = unserialize($data['column_name']);
```

Now, you can display the data however you want, accessing each value with `$blob['label']` or `$blob['days']`.